# Remote Objects Criteria - null values

Tags: remote-objects, criteria

Is it possible to retrieve objects with null in given field? How to create such a criterion object?
Something like:

```
{where:
       {fieldname: 
                  {eq : null }
       }
}
```

doesn't return any values.
There is nothing about what to do about this case in documentation : [criterion object format](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm)

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce/Apex?

Comment: It is related to Visualforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code snippet:

```
{where:
   {fieldname: 
              {eq : ''}
   }
}
```

Note that you should not pass null instead you need to pass '' empty string.

Comment: Additional question: Is it possible to make empty criterion - without any criteria?

Comment: empty criterion = no criterion , so you just need to skip the complete where block.